# Disabling horizontal scroll+movement on responsive website where some elements are absolutely positioned

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a responsive website where I disabled horizontal scroll with

```
body{ overflow-x: hidden }
```

but I still have an issue that in touch devices I can move my screen right (or in desktop browser with right arrow key)

The trick is that I have an Css3 animation that is moving elements from `margin-left: 1000px` to `margin-left: -1000px`.

I tried to re-factor the code to absolute position as well `left: 1000px` to `left: -1000px` with same problem

I even tried to use:  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no" />`

or to add additional `html{ overflow-x: hidden }`

nothing have worked,

anyone got any other ideas how to disable the movement to right so that my design stay responsive and I can keep the element (clouds) animation ?

the website: http://www.eq8.eu

thx

Answer (score 0):

What i suggest is to leave the overflow on the body alone. make your wrappers for each section overflow hidden with a `max-width: 100%;` This will stop your page from scrolling horizontally and still allow me to go down the page when the content does not fit the screen. I also think putting `box-sizing: border-box;` (with all the vendor prefixes) is a good way to avoid your boxes from being pushed out of their container from padding and borders.